# How to do paging in MS SQL query?

Tags: sql-server

What is the easiest way for paging in MS SQL? I have tried nested queries where I select TOP results and then reverse order and select TOP in the result again. But is there any way like LIMIT in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try OFFSET FETCH clause of MS SQL Server 2012 . See  link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx

Comment: But only in SQL Server 2012+ :(

Comment: @user2864740 Yes you are correct I checked the article. Thankfully I am using MS SQL server 2012

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
DECLARE @OffsetRows tinyint = 0
, @FetchRows tinyint = 20;

SELECT Id, Data, Date
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Date
OFFSET @OffsetRows ROWS
FETCH NEXT @FetchRows ROWS ONLY;
```